I cannot see the index.html page in spring boot
package crv_coders.ainews.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;


@Controller
public class ViewController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "index";
    }
}

localhost8080
project structure
When i go to localhost8080 i don t see the HTML page.
The only solve I got was to move the HTML page to the statics folder.

By default Spring Boot serves static files like html from following locations: /META-INF/resources/, /resources/, /static/,
/public/ see here. You can specify another location with property: spring.web.resources.static-locations=classpath:/files/,classpath:/static-files

This is the expected behavior.
If you are using a static HTML file, then it should be served from src/main/resources/static as a static resource. The src/main/resources/templates folder is dedicated to template files for template engines.
I guess in your case the index page is static and doesn't need any template engine and it's fine. If your application requires templated pages, you should add a new dependency in your application build file to add this capability. For example, Thymeleaf and Mustache are quite popular for this.
